# rasterio - load multi-dimensional data

Tags: python-3.x, rasterio

I just discovered rasterio for easy raster handling in Python. I am working with multi-dimensional climate data (4D and 5D). I was successful to open and read my `4D-NetCDF` file with rasterio `(lat: 180, lon: 361, time: 6, number: 51)`. However, the rasterio dataset object shows me three dimensions `(180, 361, 306)`, whereby dimension 3 and 4 were combined. Can rasterio dataset objects only store 3 dimensions?

If yes, how does rasterio combine dimensions 3 and 4, to know what layer of the 306 resembles the original?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`rasterio` is really not the tool of choice for multi-dimensional netCDF data. It excels at handling 3D `(band, y, x)` data where `band` is some relatively short, unlabeled axis.

Look into `xarray` instead, which is built around the netCDF model and supports labeled axes and many dimensions, plus lazy loading, out-of-memory computation, plotting, indexing, ...